# Flutter - Video Rcording

Tags: flutter, audio, video

I have a feature of recording a video in my app but I dont want to take any audio input while recording the video. And at the same time I want to input an another audio into the video like a song. How can i implement this with the camera plugin?

Comment: You can checkout the camera_plugin by which you can record your video. The video_player plugin will only render your audio and video of the file , it can  not change the audio of the video you are trying to change